# why drawImage function draws my colored png images in black color?

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawimage

I have a canvas where i draw colored png stickers (stored in a folder) on it.

but the function draws all my stickers in black color.

I tried some solutions but it didn't work٫

this is my function which i call it from an onchange event inside a dropdown list.

```
function choosestickers(){
    var drop = document.getElementById("stickers");
    var sticker = drop.options[drop.selectedIndex].value;
    var img = new Image;
    img.onload = function()
    {
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 320, 240);
    }
    img.src = sticker;
}
```

Comment: there is nothing obviously wrong with your code. (https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/bqh2ueog/) You need to post more code. You can use images from imgur and use a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to put runnable code in the question itself

Comment: @gman I checked now and i found that it draws just the black and red colored png images . and it draws the other png images (with other colors) in black color

Comment: That's not helpful to anyone if you don't provide the images and the code that draws them. From the stack overflow docs: "Questions seeking debugging help, why this code doesn't work, must priovide a minimal reproducable example in the question itself. You haven't provided enough code to reproduce the issue so we have absolutely no way to help you.

Comment: @gman I think the problem is with the images i have .. thanks for your help